# Return all the results for the latest date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partition-by

I have a table with the following columns:

- `city_id` = city ID
- `city_name` = city name
- `shape` = polygon -> geography field
- `date` = date when the shape was created

and populated with the following sample data:

| city_id | city_name | shape | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((18.967481 103.314121, 18.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 18.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 18.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 18.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((12.967481 103.314121, 12.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 12.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 12.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 12.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((14.967481 103.314121, 14.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 14.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 14.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 14.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((16.967481 103.314121, 16.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 16.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 16.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 16.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-11 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((8.967481 103.314121, 8.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 8.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 8.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 8.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-11 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((22.967481 103.314121, 22.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 22.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 22.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 22.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-03-23 |
| 3 | ijkl | POLYGON((24.967481 103.314121, 24.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 24.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 24.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 24.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-10 |
| 3 | ijkl | POLYGON((28.967481 103.314121, 28.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 28.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 28.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 28.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-03-03 |

I've crafted the following query:

```
SELECT city_id, 
       city_name, 
       shape,
       date
FROM (SELECT city_id, 
             city_name, 
             ANY_VALUE(shape) AS shape, 
             date, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id, city_name ORDER BY date DESC) AS rank
      FROM test
      GROUP BY 1,2,4,5)
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Current result:

| city_id | city_name | shape | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((18.967481 103.314121, 18.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 18.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 18.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 18.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((16.967481 103.314121, 16.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 16.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 16.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 16.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-11 |
| 3 | ijkl | POLYGON((24.967481 103.314121, 24.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 24.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 24.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 24.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-10 |

With this query, I was hoping that using the `PARTITION` function and `rank = 1` would return all the records for a city where several shapes have been created the same day, for the latest date. The query works fine for cities with only 1 shape created on the latest date.

Expected output:

| city_id | city_name | shape | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((18.967481 103.314121, 18.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 18.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 18.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 18.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((12.967481 103.314121, 12.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 12.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 12.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 12.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 1 | abcd | POLYGON((14.967481 103.314121, 14.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 14.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 14.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 14.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-24 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((16.967481 103.314121, 16.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 16.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 16.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 16.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-11 |
| 2 | efgh | POLYGON((8.967481 103.314121, 8.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 8.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 8.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 8.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-11 |
| 3 | ijkl | POLYGON((24.967481 103.314121, 24.947563293673372 103.3669285559756, 24.90735564458858 103.32701845345733, 24.962686563318833 103.30510874799613, 24.967481 103.314121)) | 2023-04-10 |

Any idea on how to return all the shapes created on the latest date for each city?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Forgot to change the dates. It is now fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DENSE_RANK`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#dense_rank) window function is better used here. It's cousin [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number) allows unique ranking values only, regardless of ties.

```
SELECT city_id, city_name, shape, date
FROM (SELECT city_id, city_name, shape, date, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
      FROM test) cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Also you can remove:

- the whole `GROUP BY` clause from the subquery
- "*city_name*" from the `PARTITION BY` clause, assuming that your "*city_id*" values uniquely identify cities.

Comment: Amazing! Did not know DENSE_RANK. Thank you! It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the records of the last date for each city thin try this.

```
SELECT test.city_id, 
       test.city_name, 
       ANY_VALUE(shape) AS shape, 
       test.date
FROM test inner join (SELECT city_id, 
             city_name, 
             MAX(date) AS MAX_DATE
      FROM test
      GROUP BY city_id, city_name) m ON test.city_id = m.city_id AND test.date = m.MAX_DATE
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The query does not work.